# Python: Asking for more digit number input and making a sum of out it

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

```
number=int(input("Number: "))

sum = 0

while number:
    sum = sum + number % 10
    number /= 10

print(sum)
```

Okay, so I am trying to understand what this code actually does. I am wondering if it loops 26 times. Can someone type this out for me in words cause I have a dyslexy and I am trying to understand Python.

> I am actually trying to ask the user for a two digit number, and then
>   wanting to make a sum out of it ex. 23 would be 2+3 which equals 5

The code does work but I dont understand it. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: `while number` will keep looping until `number` is Falsey. i.e. until it's zero. Since that can never happen (*floating point arithmetic aside...*) inside the loop, it appears to be an infinite loop.

Comment: What part don't you understand?  Perhaps you should look at a tutorial instead?

Comment: Do you know what `%` and `/=` do? If so, try to "simulate" the algorithm on a piece of paper. Or just add a bunch of `print` statements to see what happens in the loop.

Comment: @John: Check my answer. I think you should understand now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ask the user for a two digit number and add the digits, you can do a bit of error checking...

```
number = input("Number: ")
if not (number.isdigit() and len(number) == 2):
    # invalid input -- handle it

tens, ones = number  # unpacking is magic!
tens = int(tens)
ones = int(ones)
# this could also be: tens, ones = map(int, number)

print(tens + ones)
```

Personally I'd rather deal with individual digits as a string than trying to *math* my way out of it. If you prefer to use math, it'd be something like:

```
number = int(number)
tens, ones = ((number - (number % 10)) % 100)//10, number % 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while number:
```

will loop until number equal 0.

```
sum = sum + number % 10
```

will add to your sum the last digit of your number
(i.e: 23 % 10 = 3  because 23 = 2 * 10 + 3)

So with your exemple of 23 you will have:

First iteration:

```
sum = 0 + 3
number = 23 /10 = 2
```

Second iteration:

```
sum = 3 + 2
number = 2 / 10 = 0
```

number = 0 so it stops.

Comment: This appears to be Python3 (judging from the `input` and the `print` calls) so `2/10` is `0.2` and it continues....

Comment: Testing it quickly looks like the `while` loop runs 325 times before floating point errors get the better of it and round down to zero.

Answer (score 0):

In **python 3**, your code will be:

```
number=int(input("Number: "))

sum = 0

while number:
    sum = sum + number % 10
    number //= 10

print(sum)
```

Lets, you get a input:

```
Number: 23
```

**Step 1:**

```
> sum = 0 `while number` is true because number=26 
> then `sum = sum + number%10` means 
> sum = 0 + 3 (3 from 23%10)
> so, sum = 3 then 
> number = 2 (number//10)
```

**Step 2:**

```
> sum = 3 `while number` is true because number=2 
> then `sum = sum + number%10` means
> sum = 3 + 2 (2 from 2%10)
> so, sum = 5 then 
> number = 0 (2//10)
```

**Step 3:**

```
`while number` is false because number=0
```

Then `while loop` will be terminated and sum will be:

```
sum = 5
```